# Are there interlinear translations of the siddur other than by Artscroll?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, english

The Artscroll interlinear siddur occassionally offers an unexpected translation.  Are there other, similar (word-by-word, not phrase by phrase) translations of the siddur (into English)?

Comment: Is "interlinear" a technical term or a made up Artscroll one? If the latter, consider describing in regular terms what you seek.

Comment: It's the term [used by linguists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss).

Comment: @DoubleAA  Collins http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interlinear?showCookiePolicy=true defines interlinear as "written or printed with the text in different languages or versions on alternate lines" which is a good description of the Artscroll interlinear siddur.

Comment: ArtScroll-Mesorah has the Interlinear translation and layout copyrighted. Because of this there's not any other siddur that has the same "stress-less" layout of the Schottenstein Interlinear Siddurim. You can find similar publications, but they will most likely be not as good. (opinion.) I know some people don't like the ArtScroll translation, but I think they have some very nice English in their siddurim. The Interlinear translation is much more superior to the classic translation though, if that helps at all.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Do you mean the interlinear is better than the regular Artscroll translation or classic translations in general?  In any case, what do you see as the superior aspects?  Personally, I like the opportunity to reflect on the translation, which usually I agree with but sometimes causes me to scratch my head.

Comment: @YehudaW - Yes, I mean the Interlinear translation is superior (slightly) to the Classic translation.

Comment: @YehudaW - Sometimes ArtScroll just uses really strange English words. Like when they say "revivify." I didn't think that was an actual English word until I looked it up and found out it was. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Siddur Besamim Rosh [Nusach Ashkenaz](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=46025) & [Nusach Sefard](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=46023) is an interlinear Siddur. They can be purchased brand new at [Jewish Used Books](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/).

Comment: Linear and interlinear are not the same.  Linear provides a line-by-line translation.  Interlinear provides a word-by-word translation.  Metsuda is linear.  I am looking for word-by-word.

Comment: Answer has been updated and now features an interlinear Siddur.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Sefardi you might find the [Siddur Sefardi haShalem by Rabbi Kohansion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TLGK6U) useful.  It has a linear translation.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Michael, and thanks for the recommendation (+1). I added a link to your post so people can see more about it. Hope to see you around.

Comment: I'm going to second Scimonster's welcome. 

I don't really think this is what the OP is looking for. This has the English running in the opposite direction to the Hebrew, which would likely make understanding it more confusing

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt that is confusing, that had to be seen to be believed!